# Spatial derivative of pendulum to time derivative

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations

$m\ddot{x}\dot{x}+\frac{dV}{dx}\dot{x}=0\Rightarrow \frac{d}{dt}\left [ \frac{1}{2}m\dot{x}^{2}+V\left ( x \right ) \right ]=0$

$Using \frac{dV\left ( x\left ( t \right ) \right )}{dt}=\frac{dV}{dx}\frac{dx}{dt}$

The transformation in the first line is a bit hard to see. Can someone help me?

Comment: Is it obvious that you can go right to left?

Comment: Yes but what about left to right?

Comment: Left to right amounts to computing $\int m \ddot{x} \dot{x} + \frac{dV}{dx} \dot{x} dt$, which can be done by a substitution. In the first term substitute $u=\dot{x}$, in the second term substitute $u=x$.

Comment: Is integration by parts required?@Ian

Comment: No, it is not. ${}{}$

Comment: I get Integrate $m\dot{u}dx+\frac{dV}{dx}dx$@Ian

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by any of that. You should find that $\int m \ddot{x} \dot{x} dt = \int m u du = \frac{1}{2} m u^2 = \frac{1}{2} m \dot{x}^2$ and $\int \frac{dV}{dx} \dot{x} dt = \int \frac{dV}{dw} dw = V(w)=V(x)$, where $u=\dot{x}$ and $w=x$.

Comment: @Ian Why do you need to integrate? $\frac{d}{dt}[\frac{1}{2}m\dot{x}^2] = m\dot{x}\ddot{x}$ is a simple identity.

Comment: @Winther That gives the equation going from right to left. asdas seems to want to know how to derive the equation going from left to right.

Comment: @Ian That makes sense, thanks. I got the impression it was about proving it.